# SimpleCursorAdapter error: column does not exist - only happens in Android 2.1

Tags: android, cursor, expandablelistview, simplecursoradapter, android-2.1-eclair

I have an activity that extends `ExpandableListActivity`. I have no issues when I run the application on Android 2.2+. However, when I run it on an Android 2.1 emulator, this activity force closes (the other activities in the app have no issues). I am completely stumped.

I have created a custom adapter to use with the `ExpandableListView` that extends `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`. I am setting up the list adapter using the following code:

```
customExpandableListAdapter = new BeerFlightsExpandableListAdapter(
                                    this,                                           // context
                                    beerFlights,                                    // cursor
                                    R.layout.beer_flight_list_item,                 // group layout
                                    new String[]{"_id", "name"},                    // group FROM
                                    new int[] {R.id.flight_id, R.id.flight_name},   // group TO
                                    R.layout.beer_flight_beer_list_item,            // child layout
                                    new String[]{"_id", "name"},                    // child FROM
                                    new int[]{R.id.beer_id, R.id.beer_name});       // child TO
setListAdapter(customExpandableListAdapter);
```

I am using the following code to get the **group** cursor:

```
String sql =
        "SELECT beer_flights._id, beer_flights.name, COUNT(beer_flight_beers.beer_id) AS beer_count"+
        " FROM beer_flight_beers"+
            " INNER JOIN beer_flights ON beer_flight_beers.beer_flight_id = beer_flights._id"+
            " INNER JOIN beer_locations ON beer_flights.location_id = beer_locations.location_id AND beer_locations.beer_id = beer_flight_beers.beer_id"+
        " WHERE beer_flights.location_id = ?"+
        " GROUP BY beer_flights._id"+
        " ORDER BY beer_flights.priority ASC";

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{ locationId.toString() });
```

I am using the following code to get the **child** cursor:

```
String sql =
        "SELECT DISTINCT beers._id, beers.name, beers.brewery"+
        " FROM beer_flight_beers"+
            " INNER JOIN beers ON beer_flight_beers.beer_id = beers._id"+
            " INNER JOIN beer_flights ON beer_flight_beers.beer_flight_id = beer_flights._id"+
            " INNER JOIN beer_locations ON beer_flights.location_id = beer_locations.location_id AND beer_flight_beers.beer_id = beer_locations.beer_id"+
        " WHERE beer_flight_beers.beer_flight_id = ?"+
        " ORDER BY beers.name ASC";

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{ flightId.toString() });
```

As I said, this works perfectly in the emulators for Android 2.2+ as well as on my Droid 2 running 2.3.3 and my Droid 4 running 2.3.6. However, when I run the same code in an Android 2.1 emulator, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.absolutemg.jlbeers/com.absolutemg.jlbeers.BeerFlights}:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'name' does not exist

[snip]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'name' does not exist
at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
at android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.initFromColumns(SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java:194)
at android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.initGroupFromColumns(SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java:200)
at android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.init(SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java:180)
at android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java:169)
at com.absolutemg.jlbeers.BeerFlights$BeerFlightsExpandableListAdapter.<init>(BeerFlights.java:395)
at com.absolutemg.jlbeers.BeerFlights.onCreate(BeerFlights.java:100)
```

Both cursors have columns of **_id** and **name**. So I'm not sure why I'm getting an error saying that `column 'name' does not exist`.

I tweaked things to change the **parent** cursor to return columns of **flight_id** and **flight_name** and changed the list adapter accordingly. When I did, then the activity no longer crashed. It displayed my group names. However, when I clicked on on of the groups to open it up, it force closed again.

These same changes caused the activity to force close in Android 2.2+ (I'm assuming because I don't have a column named **_id** in my cursor). So this really isn't a fix.

Was there something different with cursors or the `rawQuery()` function in 2.1 that was changed in 2.2? I'm at a complete loss here as to how to fix this issue.

I'd love to drop support for Android 2.1 for this app, but we do have some users running 2.1 (it's only about 1.26% of our user base, but I don't want to exclude anyone from the updated app).

None of the other questions I've found here in SO have been quite the same as this, and I've had no luck finding anything anywhere else. Any ideas?

Comment: 2.1 may have a different sqlite version from newer phones with other requirements. I suppose you already checked that the case and that the  table name is "name" in lower case?

Comment: Yep ... the case of the sql query is correct. It turned out that I needed do a `beer_flights.name as name` in my query. Not sure why. Maybe because it's prefixed with a table name. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix things ... only a few minutes after posting. And the solution makes me feel like a fool. :(

I modified the queries for my cursors to explicitly set the column name, like so:

**Group Cursor**

```
SELECT beer_flights._id AS _id, beer_flights.name AS name, COUNT(beer_flight_beers.beer_id) AS beer_count
```

**Child Cursor**

```
SELECT DISTINCT beers._id AS _id, beers.name AS name, beers.brewery AS brewery
```

After I did that, everything worked as it was supposed to in all versions of Android that I am testing.

Does anyone have any clue **WHY** I need to do that for Android 2.1 but not for any later version? It seems silly to me, but that's what fixed things.

Maybe it was because the query has the table names prefixing the columns. That's my only guess at this point.

Comment: In my experience, Android 2.1 has a buggy Sqlite implementation. I've had JOINs just totally not work in 2.1 that worked fine in 2.2+. Also since you solved the problem, you should go ahead and accept your answer.